# Calling ajax inside ajax html return prevents first ajax script from further working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
...
...
<form id="validate_mail" action="/wp-content/custom-php/validate_mail.php" method="POST">
    <input name="mail_name" type="text" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<div id="validate_mail_result"></div> // placeholder for html code that is returned
<script> // main script
    var form=$('#validate_mail');
    form.submit(function(ev){
        $.ajax({
            type    : form.attr('method'),
            url     : form.attr('action'),
            data    : form.serialize(),
            success : function(result{
                $('#validate_mail_result').html(result);
            }
        });
        ev.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

**PHP** (which is called by the main script)

```
<?php
    ...
    ...
    // Connect to MySQL
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "myusername";
    $password = "mypassword";
    $connection = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        printf("MyErrorMsg: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    // Perform request
    $mail_name = $_POST[mail_name];
    $full_mail_name = $mail_name . "@mydomain.me";
    $connection->select_db("MAILSERVER");
    $queryMailExists = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE mailname = '" . $mail_name . "'";
    $resultMailExists = $connection->query($queryMailExists);
    $row_cnt = $resultMailExists->num_rows;
    $connection->close();
    if (is_valid_email_address_5321($full_mail_name)==0){
        echo "Not a valid email-address according to RFC5321";
    }elseif(row_cnt==0){ //check if email name allready taken 
        echo "Mail available";
        echo "
        <form id=\"purchase_mail\" action=\"/wp-content/custom-php/purchase_mail.php\" method=\"POST\">
            <input id=\"password\" style=\"width: 280px;\" name=\"password\" type=\"password\" value=\"\" />
            <div id=pswrd_struct_chk></div>
            <input id=\"password_retyped\" style=\"width: 280px;\" name=\"password_retyped\" type=\"password\" value=\"\" />
            <div id=pswrd_match_chk></div>
            <script> // this script and the one after this are blocking the main script
                var form=$('#purchase_mail');
                $('#password').keyup(function(ev){
                    $.ajax({
                        type    : form.attr('method'),
                        url     : \"/wp-content/custom-php/password_structure_check.php\",//just checks if the password strength  is weak/acceptable/good
                        data    : form.serialize(),
                        success : function(result){
                            $('#pswrd_struct_chk').html(result);
                        }
                    });
                    $('#password_retyped').val(\"\");
                    $('#pswrd_match_chk').html(\"\");
                });
            </script>
            <script>
                var form=$('#purchase_mail');
                $('#password_retyped').keyup(function(ev){
                    $.ajax({
                        type    : form.attr('method'),
                        url     : \"/wp-content/custom-php/password_match_check.php\",
                        data    : form.serialize(),
                        success : function(result){
                            $('#pswrd_match_chk').html(result);
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>
            <input type=\"submit\" value=\"PAY\" />
        ";
    }else{
         echo "<div>Mailname allready taken!</div>";
    }
?>
```

When i comment out the two last scripts everything works as intended. The 3 different `if`-cases in the PHP do echo their html codes into the placeholder but when i leave the scripts uncommented once the "`elseif(row_cnt==0)`" section is executed the main script gets stuck and i do not get any echo for the other two `if`-cases no matter what is submited (enterd in the input field with the `id=mail_name`).

I was not able to google my problem.

Thanks for your time end effort.

Comment: That seems like a messy way to validate emails? Why not create a simple PHP script that checks the DB only, and keep the javascript on the main page from the getgo.

Comment: missing `</form>` tag in PHP rsponse is a typo? Also `success : function(result{` seems to be incorrect syntax (in HTML).

Comment: `row_cnt` needs a `$`...  This is a PHP script, right?  Did you look at your Error Logs at all?  They would have mentioned this...  :-D

Comment: *"When i comment out the two last scripts everything works as intended"* Having a hard time figuring out what you mean by the last two scripts.

Comment: When you don't comment out the *"last two scripts"* what happens? Why does it fail? have you checked your browser's console? If not, you asked this question prematurely.

Comment: Depending on what version of jquery you are using you would use the 'live' method for older ones and 'on' with the new ones https://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Good news, your code works pretty well on my local server. Just had to fix some typos that may be causing your code to get stuck. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 4):

AJAX does not allow script tags to be passed in the results when type is HTML. Supposing that you somehow manage to pass the scripts, you will still have to retrigger the script which is somewhat bothersome.

I would suggest you to write the html adding code in the success message and passing on the variables such as form action, URLs, etc from PHP. This way you won't face those issues and you will also be able to get the job done.

Answer (score 2):

I checked your code. You can try doing something like:
**First AJAX:**

```
$.ajax({
//logic for the first ajax
}).done(function(){
//**second ajax**
})
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should follow the rule:

**in php script - just php code**, no js and css; **in js script - just js**, no css.**

It not just a good style, it will help you to facilitate your work!

I just move your html and js from validate_mail.php to main page, and it looks like:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <form id="validate_mail" action="/wp-content/custom-php/validate_mail.php" method="POST">
            <input name="mail_name" type="text" value="" />
            <input id="btn_validate_mail" type="button" value="submit" />
        </form>
        <div id="validate_mail_result1" style="display: none;">Not a valid email-address according to RFC5321</div>
        <div id="validate_mail_result2" style="display: none;">
            Mail available
            <form id="purchase_mail" action="/wp-content/custom-php/purchase_mail.php" method="POST">
                <input id="password" style="width: 280px;" name="password" type="password" value="" />
                <div id="pswrd_struct_chk"></div>
                <input id="password_retyped" style="width: 280px;" name="password_retyped" type="password" value="" />
                <div id="pswrd_match_chk"></div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="validate_mail_result3" style="display: none;">Mailname allready taken!</div>
    </body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('#btn_validate_mail').click(function () {
            var form = $('#validate_mail');
            $.ajax({
                type: form.attr('method'),
                url: form.attr('action'),
                data: form.serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#validate_mail_result'+result).show();
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    // If you will receive any errors - you will see it here.
                    console.log(error);
                },
                complete: function () {
                    form.hide();
                }
            });
        });
        $('#password').keyup(function(ev){
            var form=$('#purchase_mail');
            $.ajax({
                type    : form.attr('method'),
                url     : "/wp-content/custom-php/password_structure_check.php",//just checks if the password strength  is weak/acceptable/good
                data    : form.serialize(),
                success : function(result){
                    $('#pswrd_struct_chk').html(result);
                }
            });
            $('#password_retyped').val("");
            $('#pswrd_match_chk').html("");
        });
        $('#password_retyped').keyup(function(ev){
            var form=$('#purchase_mail');
            $.ajax({
                type    : form.attr('method'),
                url     : "/wp-content/custom-php/password_match_check.php",
                data    : form.serialize(),
                success : function(result){
                    $('#pswrd_match_chk').html(result);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

It looks much better, but still terrible. And js don't should be here, and css too.

Now validate_mail.php looks:

```
<?php

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "myusername";
    $password = "mypassword";
    $connection = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        printf("MyErrorMsg: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    // Perform request
    $mail_name = $_POST['mail_name'];
    $full_mail_name = $mail_name . "@mydomain.me";
    $connection->select_db("MAILSERVER");
    $queryMailExists = "SELECT id FROM users2 WHERE mailname = '" . $mail_name . "'";
    $resultMailExists = $connection->query($queryMailExists);
    $row_cnt = $resultMailExists->num_rows;
    $connection->close();
    if (is_valid_email_address_5321($full_mail_name)==0){
        echo 1;
    }elseif($row_cnt==0){ //check if email name allready taken 
        echo 2;
    }else{
         echo 3;
    }
```

So much easier...

I don't want talk about xss, sql injections and else, because your question not about it, but you should remember about it.

You need to continue separate js and html and css...

I just try to show how it can be much easier to reach what you need... hope it will be helpful...

Answer (score 2):

Good news. You just had typos in your code. I ran the relevant parts on a local server and your scripts are executing as expected. Enjoy!

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="validate_mail" action="validate_mail.php" method="POST">
            <input name="mail_name" type="text" value="" />
            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
        <div id="validate_mail_result"></div>
        <script> // main script
            var form = $('#validate_mail');
            form.submit(function(ev){
                $.ajax({
                    type    : form.attr('method'),
                    url     : form.attr('action'),
                    data    : form.serialize(),
                    // success : function(result{ <-- typo
                    success : function(result){
                        $('#validate_mail_result').html(result);
                    }
                });
                ev.preventDefault();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**PHP - validate_mail.php**

```
<?php
    // }elseif(row_cnt==0){     <-- typos here too, maybe more above, didn't check
    // }else if($row_cnt == 0){ 

        echo "Mail available";
        echo "
        <form id=\"purchase_mail\" action=\"/wp-content/custom-php/purchase_mail.php\" method=\"POST\">
            <input id=\"password\" style=\"width: 280px;\" name=\"password\" type=\"password\" value=\"\" />
            <div id=pswrd_struct_chk></div>
            <input id=\"password_retyped\" style=\"width: 280px;\" name=\"password_retyped\" type=\"password\" value=\"\" />
            <div id=pswrd_match_chk></div>
            <script> // this script and the one after this are blocking the main script
                var form=$('#purchase_mail');
                $('#password').keyup(function(ev){
                    $.ajax({
                        type    : form.attr('method'),
                        url     : \"/wp-content/custom-php/password_structure_check.php\",//just checks if the password strength  is weak/acceptable/good
                        data    : form.serialize(),
                        success : function(result){
                            $('#pswrd_struct_chk').html(result);
                        }
                    });
                    $('#password_retyped').val(\"\");
                    $('#pswrd_match_chk').html(\"\");
                });
            </script>
            <script>
                var form=$('#purchase_mail');
                $('#password_retyped').keyup(function(ev){
                    $.ajax({
                        type    : form.attr('method'),
                        url     : \"/wp-content/custom-php/password_match_check.php\",
                        data    : form.serialize(),
                        success : function(result){
                            $('#pswrd_match_chk').html(result);
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>
            <input type=\"submit\" value=\"PAY\" />
        ";
    //}else{
    //    echo "<div>Mailname allready taken!</div>";
    //}
?>
```

Comment: Hello, were you able to verify that this indeed solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the already-mentioned errors here (invalid HTML, invalid PHP, etc.), your easiest (and best) solution to this is simply to refactor your code so it doesn't return the HTML/JS. Just put all of the HTML/JS that is currently being returned by the PHP into your page and hide it. Have the PHP return a status code of some sort ("invalid-email"/"ok"/"taken", etc.) and have jQuery hide/unhide the appropriate response on the page. This keeps a separation of concerns between your presentation and your business logic.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery version 1.7 and above

Change

```
var form=$('#validate_mail');
form.submit(function(ev){
    $.ajax({
```

To:

```
var $(document).on('submit','#validate_mail',function(ev){
    $.ajax({
```

Also try and keep your JQuery scripts together maybe in a main.js file and definitely outside and away from your PHP. So you should write the JS for the #purchase_mail directly under your #validate_mail submit function in the same way as I described and it will work when you ajax your form into the page.

The script you are pulling in with Ajax will not work unless you evaluate eval() it somehow but doing that will open your script up to potential security vulnerabilities.

Hope that helps dude